# Does Java have a built in method to determine if an identifier is legal

Tags: java

Naming a variable or class, for example, must adhere to certain rules (such as not allowing keywords or reserved words as identifiers)

I really don't want to code my own method to do such a thing. Does java have something already built in?

My goal is that I am building an expression builder / code generator. It will recognize user specified variables and these must respect java's identifier rules or a warning is presented to user to rename his variable.

Comment: If you are authoring your DSL/language consider a tool like antlr. Food for thought...

Comment: Can't you just mange the names internally so that you're sure they Java compliant? name = "JAVASAFE_" + identifier. That'll save you from having to import anything.

Comment: @James, under the circumstances, this is probably the best answer and I will adopt this approach, thanks for that!!

Comment: Interesting that the code language and the text to be examined have to be the same language. Doesn’t that mean an end user will have to know the Java language? What if you rewrite the app in C# or C++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to look at `JavaUtils.isJavaKeyword()` ... it's not part of the Java API though, it's part of [Apache Axis](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/util/JavaUtils.html).

Comment: Please consider adding a personal explanation for why you recommend this particular product.  One line and link answers that don't explain anything will be deleted.  Thank you.

Comment: @maple_shaft The method name itself seems to describe accurately and completely everything that we need to know. There doesn't seem to actually be any further explanation that the answerer could have given that isn't already present in the name of the method he's recommending.

Answer (score 9):

To check single chars / code points:

- [`Character.isJavaIdentifierStart`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isJavaIdentifierStart-int-)
- [`Character.isJavaIdentifierPart`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isJavaIdentifierPart-int-)

To check complete identifiers:

- [`SourceVersion.isIdentifier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/SourceVersion.html#isIdentifier-java.lang.CharSequence-) (allows keywords)
- [`SourceVersion.isName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/SourceVersion.html#isName-java.lang.CharSequence-) (does not allow keywords; checks qualified name i.e. `com.example.Test` is valid)
  In Java 9 an [overload](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/lang/model/SourceVersion.html#isName-java.lang.CharSequence-javax.lang.model.SourceVersion-) accepting a `SourceVersion` has been added.

---

When working with source files, keep in mind that parts of an identifier can be [unicode escaped](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3). The above mentioned methods do not consider this.

Example:

`Main.java`

```
class Main {
    // Field 'foo'
    private String \u0066oo;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Guess I will borrow from JavaUtils code then :)

```
static final Collator englishCollator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
static final String keywords[] = {
                 "abstract",  "assert",       "boolean",    "break",      "byte",      "case",
                 "catch",     "char",         "class",      "const",     "continue",
                 "default",   "do",           "double",     "else",      "extends",
                 "false",     "final",        "finally",    "float",     "for",
                 "goto",      "if",           "implements", "import",    "instanceof",
                 "int",       "interface",    "long",       "native",    "new",
                 "null",      "package",      "private",    "protected", "public",
                 "return",    "short",        "static",     "strictfp",  "super",
                 "switch",    "synchronized", "this",       "throw",     "throws",
                 "transient", "true",         "try",        "void",      "volatile",
                 "while"
             };


     public static boolean isJavaKeyword(String keyword) {
                return (Arrays.binarySearch(keywords, keyword, englishCollator) >= 0);
     }
```

Comment: Instead of messing with a collator and binary search, why not use a Set? And you'll also need to check Character.isJavaIdentifierPart() and Character.isJavaIdentifierStart().

Comment: I can simplify this for my particular needs, I only need to ensure keywords are not used (my variables can only consist of letters and digits and underscores)   Doesn't have to match all of javas identifier rules (mine will be more restrictive, again to keep it simple)

Comment: That list of keywords is missing "enum"

Answer (score 2):

[JJavaName](https://github.com/UnquietCode/JCodeModel/blob/master/codemodel/src/main/java/com/sun/codemodel/JJavaName.java) in Sun's JCodeModel has the following method:

```
/**
 * Checks if a given string is usable as a Java identifier.
 */
public static boolean isJavaIdentifier(String s) {
    if(s.length()==0)   return false;
    if( reservedKeywords.contains(s) )  return false;

    if(!Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(s.charAt(0)))   return false;

    for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++)
        if (!Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(s.charAt(i)))
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Unfortunately, the `reservedKeywords` field is private and there's no `isReservedWord` method, but if the goal is to validate a String as an identifier, this is ideal.

Comment: Is it correct to check characters and not code points? What if a surrogate pair is a valid java identifier character?

Comment: An excellent point - the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isJavaIdentifierPart-char-) for `Character.isJavaIdentifierPart` states "Note: This method cannot handle supplementary characters. To support all Unicode characters, including supplementary characters, use the isJavaIdentifierPart(int) method." - so it seems the method ought to be checking code points, instead.